# Looking for a tool to create a digital multiplication quiz

Tags: primary-education, online-instruction, multiplication-table

I'm looking for some site or software which can help me create an easy, digital multiplication quiz for my students. Some things which need to be included:

- The student need to be able to type in the answer him/herself, no multiple choice.
- A timer which shows total time spent.
- All the questions are based on the multiplication table, so if there's a way to randomize number ranges (eg 2-10) and decide the number of questions, that would make it even easier.

Thanks!

Comment: just to clarify, you want a timer that shows the total time it took to solve all of the problems or a countdown timer like for a time limit?

Comment: Good point, I'm looking for a timer that shows the total time NOT a time limit.

Comment: i feel like there should be a way to do this using google forms....will post answer if i figure anything out

Comment: http://projects.elienasrallah.com/Cog/mental-calculation/ works only with addition and multiplicaton.

Comment: Regarding measuring timing: you may not be measuring the speed of the students' math recall, but rather their manual dexterity. Taking tests on a computer that possibly requires moving a hand to the mouse to select the answer field, moving the hand back to the keyboard to type the answer, moving the hand back to the mouse to click the "OK" button, etc. It's even worse if the students are very young, or you're using laptops with chiclet keyboards, or they're testing on a phone or small tablet where the click targets can be tiny. At some point this turns into a UX matter rather than math.

Comment: @shoover Excellent point. For my students this is not a huge problem as the tool is meant for the kids that are struggling with multiplication and thus they will likely spend quite some time on most questions. One way to make this problem smaller, however, would be to make the answer box already highlighted so the kids can just type the answer and make the enter key submit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation: http://nilock.github.io/MathSnips/MultQuiz/MultQuiz.html

edit:

This was a bit of a seat-of-pants stream-of-consciousness hack job, so the flexibility of the platform going forward is not great.

Usage should be mostly self-explanatory, but I'll mention that the system is biased against questions involving 0 and 1 (eg, it will produce fewer such questions on average) so I suggest including them in your prescribed quizzes. The 'link' updates itself as you change the configuration values. You can configure a quiz with, say, 5 questions and multiplicands between 2 and 7, and load this quiz directly with the link http://nilock.github.io/MathSnips/MultQuiz/MultQuiz.html?numQ=5&min=2&max=7&maxmin=10. This link, in turn, can be fed into a url shortening service such as tinyurl.com in order to produce a url that can be more easily communicated / manually typed. For example, the above configuration has been fed into tinyurl which produced the link [tinyurl.com/m8esp94](http://tinyurl.com/m8esp94).

Further extension of this particular page will be limited, but I'm happy to keep the current implementation in working order. Where defects are found on this page, the best option is to post them to https://github.com/NiloCK/MathSnips/issues with the New Issue button in the upper right. Posts there will land in my inbox, which is more reliably read than a Stack Exchange push notification.

I have ideas toward a similar but more generalized and robust system, but that's a long term project. I'll post it here should I ever get it off the ground.

Comment: I notice now that there's no 'timing' info being displayed. It's being tracked under the hood but I'm on my way to bed - will fix up tomorrow.

Comment: This is great, thanks for doing this! If you have the time a clock would be great, also the posibility for minimum number (eg 2 to avoid questions like 0*4 and 1*7). This is for kids, so to make it even easier for them,  a way for me to set the "rules" and just give them a link to a finished quiz so they don't do anything else than solving the quiz, would be nice.

Comment: Do you have a way to send a link directly to the kids, or will it be transferred orally and typed? It's easy enough to configure the quiz via a query string. Eg, the url `http://nilock.github.io/MathSnips/MultQuiz/MultQuiz.html?numQ=10&min=2&max=10` would produce a ten question quiz with multiplicands between two and 10 inclusive, but that's a bit of a mouthful for young kids to type (and type correctly).

Comment: I can send it to them and create the link so that will work fine!  If I need to put it out orally I could use tinyurl or something similar.

Comment: I updated the quiz setup page so that the customization options can be better understood. Suggestion: leave one of Max and MaxMin at ten and adjust the other - you'll figure out what they mean. Please suggest better labels for them if you can think of them.

Comment: I'll fix it tonight so that 1) the quiz-taking experience is improved, 2) the quiz creation thingy produces a link in the above format to particular configurations, and 3) quiz-takers will have the option to retry a given quiz, and attempt to beat previous attempts in both accuracy and time.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for not coming back to you sooner NiloCK. I think the quiz looks great! I'll make sure the kids know there are great people out there doing this for total unknowns. I'll hopefully get to start using this next week. 

And now this is me being greedy, but if you have the time and will to implement numbers up to 20, and if possible show time spent on each question.

Comment: And one more thing I forgot, do you believe the quiz can stay on the page you provided, or should I somehow copy it to somewhere else (I'll figure)?

Comment: Numbers up to 20 is no problem, (actually this would work now if you manually put it into the url, eg `max=20`) but I'll leave the preview box as it stands now, since it will become unwieldy - it will be up to the user to extrapolate the expected result of bigger quizzes. Will look into timing per question. I also have a mostly complete graphical representation of the current session's cumulative results, eg, the preview table where individual questions are colored in a red-to-green scale which reflects the performance on those questions.

Comment: Hosting indefinitely at that address is not a problem, but after I clue up this thing I'll also put together something that's easily downloadable in a package so that the page can be served wherever or run locally (eg, without internet).

Comment: Appreciate this so much, please let me know if there is anything I can do in return.

Comment: I tried using higher numbers than 10 @Nilock, and they're interpreted into the questions, but they're not possible to submit (nothing happens when hitting enter or "submit").

Comment: @attenboro Whoops. Looks like it's trying to record the score of the question, but the scoresheet itself only has space for up to 10x10. Will fix tonight. Going forward, I'd prefer for problems with this page to be posted at https://github.com/NiloCK/MathSnips/issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an iOS app that does this (and a lot more); it allows kids to use their voice to provide answers and also provides a number of learning activities.

You can see some details here: http://multiplywithme.com (learning activities are not on the website yet). We are beta testing the app; if you are interested in trying it out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Maths Trainer]

http://www.mathsisfun.com/flash.php?path=/numbers/images/math-trainer.swf?m=Multiply&w=960&h=750&col=%23FFFFFF&title=Math+Trainer+-+Multiplication

If you make a mistake, it will flash the correct answer for a second and wait for you to put the correct answer in.

It will then give you a summary of how well you did and how many right and wrong. 
Really helps with memorising less multiplications as it drills $5\times3=3\times5$

But I will stress that it is important that the kids understand what multipying means "groups of" and that they can actually answer worded problems and solve unseen questions with multiplcation (something not so repetitive). It is too late for them to learn this in high school.

Comment: Please summarize the link. Many people around here don't want to go clicking around, and the linked to page might dissappear at any time, making the answer useless.